# magento same product with different prices

Tags: magento, product

I am currently making a magento-based e-commerce site, and I want my single product to have multiple prices.

My problem is, I don't know how to do it in my product with different prices. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention the purpose of multiple prices. if you want different price for different customer group then you can use group price and if you want different price for porpuse like discount or sale then you can use special price.

For other puupose, please refer below link and acknowledge if it is helpful or not.

[manufacturers-suggested-retail-price](http://siven76.com/2013/03/08/magento-display-manufacturers-suggested-retail-price/)

Comment: In general it's better to include the code here instead of links, as pages might disappear.

Comment: Thank you for your response...But I did some changes through the use of magento's admin panel and it works..